# Destroy/remove bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

First, I created a virtual carousel (carousel elements) and then initialize it

```
$('#first-carousel').carousel();
```

Now, I run unto scenario where if window width is less than 480 then remove that carousel (#first-carousel').

How to remove bootstrap carousel? Tried to check its doc but seems there's no something like destroy or remove function or any related. Tried

```
$('#first-carousel').remove();
$('#first-carousel').unbind();
```

but seems not working, instead it gives me this error

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'offsetWidth' of undefined
>           at c.slide (bootstrap.min.js:6)
>           at c.next (bootstrap.min.js:6)
>           at e (jquery.min.js:2)

any help, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there are no way to do it in Boostrap 3. What you can do is only initialize the carousel if the viewport is greater or equal to 480px.

```js
if(window.innerWidth >= 480){
  $('#first-carousel').carousel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `$('#first-carousel').remove();` does remove the element with that given id. You might be having an issue with the condition for window width possibly, are you sure you aren't having a different issue here?

Comment: Again, tried .remove() but it gives me this error "bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
    at c.slide (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at c.next (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)"

Comment: The given method would not be returning the error you are receiving, which is why I ask if you could maybe check or provide where you are actually getting this error. I have added a carousel with the same id as you have shown, removed it with .remove() and it causes no errors. The element is actually removed from the html fully.

Comment: I tried it with the latest cdn from bootstrap site as well on this: https://jsfiddle.net/4qk0thx3/ -- Works just as my local attempt, with an actual carousel I was using in one of my sites.